# Ubuntu 16.04 - Having both KDE and Gnome

Tags: kde, lightdm

I have installed gnome on my ubuntu 16.04 with lightdm. Can i install KDE too and select kde or gnome on the login screen? or lightdm will be lost?

Answer (score 1):

You can install both KDE and Gnome on the same system and keep lightdm. However from personal experience I found that installing the `kubuntu-desktop` package with gnome did not work as there were package conflicts and when I installed the `plasma-desktop` it installed and ran but it was not seamless and a few of the KDE features did not work. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes the reason i asked is because i install kubuntu-desktop with lightdm but... when i logged in with plasma all i saw was a black screen... how do you fix that?.. or can u tell me the correct way to install KDE ?

Comment: @NikosL24 If I needed a KDE desktop then I would install the `plasma-desktop` as there are no dependency/package conflict issues. however as mentioned in my answer I would not at all recommend it. a better way to do it may be to start with a clean install of Kubuntu and then try to install gnome however I have not tried that so do not know how it would work.

Comment: so with ubuntu i am not able to use KDE right?

Comment: you can use kde however the way for best results would be with a Kubuntu install or just installing the `plasma-desktop` however in my experience the latter method will not yield perfect results.